Dynamic higher order scalar difference equation
Let $\Delta f = f(n+1)-f(n)$. Is there any general theory around solutions to equations of the form $$\Delta f = b_n + \sum_{k=1}^n c_{n,k}f(k)$$? If the sum had a constant amount of terms, rather than $n$, then the theory is pretty well-developed (searching for "Higher-Order Scalar Difference Equations" gives a lot of promising results, e.g. Chapter 5 in http://bmm.univ-lyon1.fr/bmm/data/references/Elaydi-2005.pdf, though $b_n$ and $c_k$ are assumed constant here). Though in the case where the amount of summands depends on $n$ itself, I was not able to find anything (or rather, I do not know what precise terms to search for).
In my case, I have the following difference equation: $$\Delta f = c_1^n c_1' + \sum_{k=1}^n c^k_1 c_1' c_2 f(n-k)$$with the initial condition $f(0) = 0$, where $c_1, c_1', c_2$ are elements of a non-commutative ring.
Any help or pointers to resources on this topic are greatly appreciated!
